# How to set up the Sites folder as a root for http://localhost macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, apache, macos-big-sur

How can I set up the Apache to user my Sites folder as a default root for the http://localhost?

I was using this tutorial to set up the localhost/~username but now I would like to use just localhost for that https://wpbeaches.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-11-big-sur-and-earlier-macos/

I've already changed the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "folder/subfolder"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I want to go to localhost/phpmyadmin it's not working, and I'm getting `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: taking a wild guess here (sarcasm) .... you don't have a folder called phpmyadmin in your default route directory